# How can I access a selected option's displayed value from a directive on the select element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My markup looks something like this

```
<select ng-model="search.parameters.selectedOptionId" ng-options="lookup.id as lookup.lookupValue for lookup in lookups.options" custom-attribute-directive>
    <option value="" selected>All</option>
</select>
```

From the customAttributeDirective, I need to access the selected option value that is displayed in the dropdown (i.e. lookup.lookupValue). I've tried accessing the $viewValue on the ngModel, but it is set to the lookup.id (which I assume is the fault of the way ng-options is set up). I cannot modify the implementation of the markup due to the circumstances that I am implementing the directive against, so the problem must be solved there.

Comment: ng-model "search.parameters.selectedOptionId" will have that selected value

Comment: it will only have the selected id. I need to extract the displayed lookupValue from the directive. updated to make the question more specific

Comment: as far as I can see in sources for ngOptionsController and SelectController there is no way to fetch options' sources through communication between controllers. So you could pass the same `lookups. options` to your directive(to keep it not-so-hard-coded) and then filter list based on value from ngModelController

Comment: The problem with that is that I would also need to pass in what value to compare on. Some of our dropdowns use id/lookupValue, some use UserId/UserName, etc. It would blow up pretty fast if I also had to pass in the parameter name to the potential value by. I ended up finding a way to do it by traversing the element provided to the directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer. It turns out directives can access the dom directly.

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller) {
    scope.getViewValue = function () {
                    if (angular.isDefined(scope.overrideTagDisplay)) {
                        return scope.overrideTagDisplay;
                    }
                    else if (element[0].nodeName == "SELECT") {
                        return element.children()[element[0].selectedIndex].text;
                    }
                    else {
                        return ngModel.$viewValue;
                    }
    }

    scope.initialize()
}
```

EDIT: I found later that this method has the issue that if javascript modifies the model value somewhere else in the code and then this piece immediately runs, it does not pick up the new value because the DOM hasn't updated (this includes on page load and initial setting). I ended up passing the list of lookups into the directive as well and got around the lack of standardization in those lookups by having an optional "comparator key" that would defaultly look something like

```
var comparitorKey = { id: "id", lookupValue: "lookupValue"};
```

which is then utilized like this

```
var id = ngModel.$modelValue;

var filtered = scope.lookupList.filter(function (lookup) { return lookup[scope.comparitorKey.id] == id });
return filtered.length > 0 ? filtered[0][scope.comparitorKey.lookupValue] : null;
```

the idea being that someone could pass in an alternative like

```
var comparitorKey = {id: "userId", lookupValue: "userName" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the lookup.lookupValue for display and lookup.lookupValue for backend Id too. In that case you will get display text with ng-model

```
<select ng-model="search.parameters.selectedOptionId" ng-options="lookup.lookupValue as lookup.lookupValue for lookup in lookups.options" custom-attribute-directive>
<option value="" selected>All</option>
```

Comment: As I stated in my initial question, due to the circumstances that I am implementing the directive against, no changes can be made to this markup, and that definitely includes changing the behavior of the id property.

Comment: Oh, then you need to store array or whatever data you are binding to dropdown and then on dropdown item change get the selected item ID and then find that item by ID from array.

Comment: I couldn't do that either because on different pages, the options vary in definition and the directive had to work anywhere where the only known common factor is that it was located on a select element and some item was being displayed. I found the answer that I was looking for and posted it, but thanks for your help.